# How to efficiently store temporary userdata

Tags: java, database, sql-update, updates

I'm fairly new to Java and I need help with something. Is there an (efficient) solution to the following problem:

I have a bot where players can "roll" to gain coins. Right now, after every single roll, the database gets edited with the updated amount of coins the user has... but that takes a huge toll on performance.

What I need:

```
User A rolls and wins 10 coins
User B rolls and wins 20 coins
User A rolls and loses 20 coins
User C rolls and wins 30 coins
User A rolls and wins 10 coins
--1 minute has ended--
--update database--
```

What I have now:

```
User A rolls and wins 10 coins
--update database--
User B rolls and wins 20 coins
--update database--
User A rolls and loses 20 coins
--update database--
User C rolls and wins 30 coins
--update database--
User A rolls and wins 10 coins
--update database--
```

Is there a good way to store the temporary user data? I was thinking about creating a new String with the Username every time a new user rolls, and link an int to it with the updated value, and pass those into the database every minute.

But I feel like there have to be a lot better solutions, I just can't think of anything..

If someone can guide me to a good method or give me an example? Would be **greatly** appreciated! Thanks in advance!

I hope my question is not too nooby..

Comment: Databases are fast, you're probably doing something inefficient like create a new connection every time you need to update.

Comment: @Kayaman That's actually what I am doing! Should I just only open the connection once in main(){} or?

Comment: Yea basically, you want to keep a connection open as long as a player is playing. By doing this you create playing sessions, you open the connection at the start of the session and close it at the end.

Comment: use StringBuffer or StringReader. you can append the values to it.

Comment: @namlik Thank you! So I just put this above main: `static Connection botDatabaseCon = null;` and then define botDatabaseCon like this inside of main: `botDatabaseCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:botDatabase.db");` and then refer to it everywhere else ? Is that the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Yea make sure you only make the connection once as seen in the answers below.

Comment: try using apache cache, or search for LRU, check if it suffice your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a local cache which contains the data for every user session. At the end of session update the user data in the database. For implementation of cache you can use **HashMap**. The key will be your user and the value will be the object of user or the number of coins.
Here is what you get:

```
User A rolls and wins 10 coins
User B rolls and wins 20 coins
User A rolls and loses 20 coins
User C rolls and wins 30 coins
User A rolls and wins 10 coins
--User A stops playing--
--update database for user A--
User C rolls and wins 30 coins
User B rolls and wins 20 coins
User C rolls and wins 10 coins
User B rolls and wins 10 coins      
--User B stops playing--
--update database for user B--
```

Here is a brief implementation:

```
public class Game
{
    private static Map<String, int> users = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, int>();

    public void endGame(Sring user) {

        //do something for user
        updateDatabase(user, users.get(user));

    }
    public void roll(String user) {
        //roll implementation
    }

    private void updateDatabase(String user, int numberOfCoins) {

        //update database for user here.
    }
}
```

Just make sure that your connection is made only once.

Comment: I used your answer and it works perfectly now! Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075440/core-java/develop-a-generic-caching-service-to-improve-performance.html

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/
You can use file read / write for temp hold of data ,(only suggestion)
Hope , it may helps !

Answer (score 2):

Create a List where you would temporarily store data and when size of the list exceeds a particular threshold, then update the database.

consider sending strings to a functions

```
List<String> userEvents = new ArrayList<String>();
private final int THRESHOLD = 10;

public void saveDataToDB(String event) {
    userEvents.add(event);
    if( userEvents.size() > THRESHOLD ) {
        boolean status DBSaver.save(userEvents);
        if( status ) {
            userEvents.clear();
        } else {
            //error condition... Handle it
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the DBSaver would be an singleton class with static connection object which would be reused.